# R how to combine X number of rows from a tibble to one long?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

How can I efficiently transform a tibble into a numeric vector?
Preferably in tidyverse.

```
#Example data 1:

x <- as_tibble(matrix(1:9, ncol=3))

wanted:
x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)


#Example data 2: 
x <- as_tibble(matrix(1:10, ncol=2))

wanted:
x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your columns are numeric you can use unlist and unname:

```
x <- as_tibble(matrix(1:10, ncol=2))
x %>% unlist() %>% unname()

[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```